# Hyperlink in custom display form

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, custom-lists

I am trying to add a field that holds a hyperlink in a custom display form. I have the following code:

```html
<td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
       <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
        <nobr>ATO</nobr>
       </H3>
      </td>
      <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
       <a href="https://intelshare.intelink.gov/sites/carm/Shared%20Documents/ATO%20Letters/' + @eMASSID + '.pdf'">
        <xsl:value-of select="@ATO"/>
       </a>      
      </td>
     </tr>
```

However it only shows the "ATO" text, it doesn't display the hyperlink. I am pretty new to using SharePoint designer so I'm not to sure where to go from here.

Comment: Can you please format your code a bit clearer, also it's unclear whether you understand what you're doing with the href=. You have a double quoted string, but then single quotes with the + operator. Is this your intent? Did you try other href without string concat within double quoted string?

Comment: the single quotes with the + operator is used to auto generate a link for a pdf document from a document library based on the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Sample test demo:

```
<tr>
                        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                <nobr>Employee Type</nobr>
                            </H3>
                        </td>
                        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                            <a href="https://intelshare.intelink.gov/sites/carm/Shared%20Documents/ATO%20Letters/{@Company_x0020_name}.pdf">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@Employee_x0020_Type"/>
                            </a>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@Employee_x0020_Type"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Sorry if I didn't elaborate enough about my question. I'm trying to figure out how I can auto generate a link each time a document is uploaded to a document library based on the ID of that document. Then that link will automatically be added to a list.